# Switch between WriteTo and AuditTo at runtime

Tags: serilog

AuditTo is a Serilog feature that ensures synchronous write to the sink, with an exception thrown if change flushing fails.As the name implies, it is ideal for ensuring the security of audit data to be stored. Right now, I found File, Seq and RabbitMQ sinks supporting AuditTo writes. I couldn't find the SqlLite sink that I'm interested in ... :(
From the other side, we have WriteTo, which batches the log entries and writes them asynchronously. There are no exceptions; it's kind of fire and forget.No one cares whether the log entries are dropped by the connection or the target system's failure or unavailability.

I would like to implement sending the audit logs via AuditTo but also be able to switch the log configuration to WriteTo at the runtime. In the meantime, the app might still write the logs. 
I saw that Serilog offers dynamic switching of the logging level via LoggingLevelSwitch.
Any suggestions, ideas, or solutions for such requirements?